# shuffling entries of one matrix based on digitzed form of another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle

I have a problem wherein I need to shuffle the entries of one matrix based on the digitized form of another.

Lets say I have a matrix filled with either 0's or 1's; `np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100, p=[.9, .1])`

I then take another matrix that is filled with values ranging from 0-4. `np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], size=100, p=[.01, 0.3, 0.3, 0.29, .1])`

What I would like to do is to rearrange the 0's and 1's according to the bins of the second matrix. So lets say I have 24 0's and 4 1's in bin 1, what I would like to do is to shuffle the entries of 0's and 1's so that they stay within bin 1 and that they maintain the same number of 0's and 1's.

I have attempted to use `np.where`, along with `np.random.shuffle` but this doesn't maintain the original count of 0's and 1's.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found a solution whereby I can loop through multiple matrices and bins.

```
a = np.array(pd.DataFrame(connections[M_a][M_b]['cMat']))

    for aw in groups:
        b = a[C_ == aw]
        np.random.shuffle(b)
        iz, jz = np.nonzero(C_ == aw)

        for i, j, v in zip(iz, jz, b):
            a[i, j] = v
```

groups in this case is the value of each bin, ranging from 0 through to n.
a is the matrix with 0's and 1's.
C_ is the digitized matrix.
iz and jz are the row and column indexes respectively. The output is the shuffled matrix.